# Facebook graph api post using "/me/feed" vs "/me/links"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've recently switch my code to post to facebook from 
https://graph.facebook.com/[profile_id]/feed
to
https://graph.facebook.com/[profile_id]/links

Now i'm getting this problem, can anyone help?
- my picture that i accompany with the post is not showing, it look like facebook is defaulting to the first image it find on the link page

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/

both of these document allow me to specify a picture, but somehow the "links" one isn't displaying the image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set correct Open Graph meta tags, especially og:image.

Comment: I've try this by adding <meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite/facebook.png"/> but this didn't seem to work, but i think i'm more interested in dynamically changing my image, not defaulting it to just one image

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved similar issue, posted news on website and posted via /links to fanpage resolved in post with wrong image content and "site not found" title.

The issue was related to wrong code sequence. We hooked posting news via fb api in not-so-good place. The post should have been already available but it wasn't and posting to fb api results in immediate request from facebookexternalhit bot to check if it exists. Detailed log analysis shown that ping from facebook was before POST to add news finished, that's why we had messed content there.

Sample content we post, if what I described above is not your case:
content_dict =
{

'picture': 'http://www.czerwonysmok.pl/static/media/uploads/blog/pb_reddragon_all2_poprawiony_czerwony.jpg/',

'message': 'Title \n\n contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent ',

'link': 'http://www.czerwony-smok.pl/klub/aktualnosci/rashguard-ze-strony/'}

```
try:
    logger.info("Publishing to facebook: " + str(content_dict))
    graph.post(path="%s/links" % settings.FAN_PAGE_ID, **content_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

About sharing on my Android app i'm using this code:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message", "User's custom message above share content");
postParams.putString("name", "The name of the link attachment.");
postParams.putString("description", "The description of the link (appears beneath the link caption). If not specified, this field is automatically populated by information scraped from the link, typically the title of the page.");
postParams.putString("caption","The caption of the link (appears beneath the link name). If not specified, this field is automatically populated with the URL of the link.");
postParams.putString("picture","The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px. See our documentation on sharing best practices for more information on sizes.");
postParams.putString("link", "The link attached to this post");
```

Refer to the document for detail: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3